# How to add Fish eye Image Filter on UIImage in iOS without using GPUImage

Tags: iphone, objective-c, c, image-processing

I want to add some filter effect on UIImage in my iPhone App. These filters are:
 1. Fish eye Filter effect.
 2. Crystallize Image effect (Same as Mosaic effect tiles in Hexagone Shape) 
 3. TV Image filter.

I've done a lots of googling and searches many regarding these filter, I got a maximum result of using GPUImage effect. I uses that but there is an issue of Cocoas2d and GPUImage conflict. in my Project I have already used cocoas 2d. So I cannot use GPUImage, please don't suggest to use GPUImage.

I want to implement these filters in some other way. but I have no idea regarding this.

I have already implemented many filters with C-Code like Saturation, Blur, Sepia, Threshold, sharpness and many more.
but struck on these 3 filters (Fisheye, Crystallizem TV)

Comment: "but there is an issue of Cocoas2d and GPUImage conflict" - specifically? Why not try to resolve that conflict instead?

Comment: are u on ios 6? you can achieve more image filters with this version of iOS otherwise i will address the issue like H2CO3 is mentioning

Comment: @tiguero
I am not on iOS 6, I know there are many filters available in iOS6 but my app has a support of iOS4 also.

Comment: @H2CO3: Cann't resolved the conflict issue, I trid many ways. like cocoas2d uses to add stump on Image it works fine but if I apply filter effects used bye GPUImage framework, a new layer is created on cocoas2d view and then stumps are not working on cocoas2d view

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should post a "Solve GPUImage and cocoas2d issues".

Also you can perfectly use GPUImage only to go from an original UIImage to a filtered UIImage independently of layers, views or any UI.

From GitHub:

```
UIImage *inputImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Lambeau.jpg"];

GPUImagePicture *stillImageSource = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:inputImage];
GPUImageSepiaFilter *stillImageFilter = [[GPUImageSepiaFilter alloc] init];

[stillImageSource addTarget:stillImageFilter];
[stillImageSource processImage];

UIImage *currentFilteredVideoFrame = [stillImageFilter imageFromCurrentlyProcessedOutput];
```

In this case inputImage and currentFilteredVideoFrame should be indiscernible for cocoas2d.

Comment: thanx @ernipiggy: but i have implemente this using ImageMagick